# Find text inside curly braces and replace text including curly braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I would like to find a pattern `{text}` and replace text including curly braces.

```
$data = 'you will have a {text and text} in such a format to do {code and code}';
$data= preg_replace_callback('/(?<={{)[^}]*(?=}})/', array($this, 'special_functions'),$data);
```

and my `special function` contain the callback code to replace the braces and completely and text conditionally.

```
public function special_functions($occurances){
        $replace_html = '';
        if($occurances){
            switch ($occurances[0]) {
                case 'text and text':
                    $replace_html = 'NOTEPAD';
                    break;
                case 'code and code':
                    $replace_html = 'PHP';
                    break;

                default:
                    $replace_html ='';
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $replace_html;
    }
```

**Expected Output**

> you will have a NOTEPAD in such a format to do PHP

How can i replace text and curly braces at the same time using `preg_replace_callback` in php using regex

Comment: Add the `special_functions` code to the question and provide expected result.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @revo Updated my question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the function to my question

Comment: Is that what you want? https://3v4l.org/759BW

Comment: @SaadSuri  Yes. can i modify that to fit in preg_replace_callback ?

Comment: Absolutely no worries

Comment: @SaadSuri I want the same functionality of what you have shown me. But i am not able to use it with my code.

Comment: do you really need preg_replace_callback?

Comment: @SaadSuri I have a switch condition that determine the replace text. So i need a replace function.

Comment: Here you go https://3v4l.org/7Qgud

Comment: So, your example must be `$data = 'you will have a {{text and text}} in such a format to do {{code and code}}'`, right? You want to get text in double braces?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew text and braces. I need both

Comment: See my answer below, it must work for you. If it does not, please provide an updated PHP fiddle showing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the pattern like this:

```
$data = preg_replace_callback('/{{([^{}]*)}}/', array($this, 'special_functions'), $data);
```

The `{{([^{}]*)}}` pattern will match:

- `{{` - `{{` substring
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}}` - a `}}` text

Then, inside the `special_functions` function, replace `switch ($occurances[0])` with `switch ($occurances[1])`. The `$occurrances[1]` is the text part captured with the `([^{}]*)` pattern. Since the whole match is `{{...}}` and the captured is `...`, the `...` is used to check the possible cases in the switch block, and the braces will get removed since they were *consumed* (=added to the match value that is replaced as a result of the `preg_replace_callback` function).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/RAvt1).

Comment: That works. I have a doubt. $occurances[0] contain text with braces and $occurances[1] contain text without braces. So logically $occurances[0] should replace both text and braces ?

Comment: @Shadow `$occurances[0]` does not replace anything. That is the text matched with `preg_replace_callback` function and hence it is the text that will be replaced.

Comment: I have upvoted. Also always what is in [1] index will be replaced. is that right ?

Comment: @Shadow Since `$occurrances[1]` is a part of `$occurrances[0]`, of course it will be replaced. `preg_replace_callback` searches for all non-overlapping matches, and replaces them with defined replacements.

Comment: So what ever the text inside curly braces the above answer works fine under all conditions ?

Comment: @Shadow Yes, but the `[^{}]*` prevents any match when the text inside `{{...}}` contains `{` or `}`. If you need them, replace `[^{}]*` with `.*?`.

Comment: Just for clarification i noticed a typo in my question that contain regex for double curly braces but my string contain only single curly braces string.

Comment: @Shadow Ok, that is not that important, remove one `{` and `}` from the pattern, `'/{([^{}]*)}/'`, definitely, no rocket science :)

Comment: if i want to find string starting with braces and a constant text should i change to `/{{MyText([^{}]*)}}/` or `/{{([^{MyText}]*)}}/`

Comment: @Shadow Look, `[^{}]` matches any single char other than `{` and `}`. Now, do you think `[^{MyText}]` makes sense?

Comment: got it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I would like to replace curly braces with sqaure. I changes the code and didn't work. Can you please help.

Comment: @Shadow Please share your non-working code via https://3v4l.org or http://ideone.com

Comment: want to change `/{addon=>([^{}]*)}/` to `/\[addon=>([^[\]]*)\]/` so as to accept text inside square bracket. In `regex101` it only matches first occurance

Comment: @Shadow Well, that is obscure. Do you want to match a string like `[addon=>text here!]`? Use `/\[addon=>([^][]*)]/`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sOokN/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a complicated regexp, you might want to look at [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx):

```
$data = 'you will have a {text and text} in such a format to do {code and code}';

pattern('{{([^{}]*)}}')
  ->replace($data)
  ->first()
  ->callback(function (Match $match) {
      switch ($match->group(1)) {
          case 'text and text':
              return 'NOTEPAD';

          case 'code and code':
              return 'PHP';

          default:
              return '';
      }
  });
```